# How to pass QDataStream as parameter to signal in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, pass-by-value, qdatastream

I am writing a method to parse a network packet in the form of a `QByteArray`. It will extract a few values using `QDataStream` and then hopefully pass the `QDataStream` along to another method for further processing (to avoid the overhead of making another `QDataStream` later).

Here is my code:

```
//datagram is QByteArray
QDataStream ds=new QDataStream(&datagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
qint64 someValue = 0;
*ds >> someValue;
emit receivePacket(ds,host, port);
```

Since I am using signals, passing by reference is not encouraged and since `QDataStream` is `Q_DISABLE_COPY` the only option left is to pass by pointer. But if I decide to pass it by pointer, how can I effectively manage the memory? (deleting it only once) later?

Comment: Maybe using QSharedPointer is an option?

Comment: That is what I did! I discovered it 5 minutes after posting this Q

Comment: In general that looks like problematic design, coupling way too much sender and receiver. IOW it's strange to emit "identity values" that then the receivers are going to modify directly... what if you then get 2 receivers, or 0 receivers?

Comment: I agree, this is bad design. Still asking the Q for the pure curiosity' sake.